# Why label2.Text in Form1 is not updating from the new class?

Tags: c#

In Form1 i have label2 in the designer and i added a code:

```
public void lbl2(string text)
        {
            label2.Text = text;
        }
```

In the new class top i added:

```
private static AnimationEditor.Form1 fr1 = new AnimationEditor.Form1();
```

And in the new class event im updating the label2.Text like this:

```
int ISampleGrabberCB.BufferCB(double sampleTime, IntPtr pBuffer, int bufferLen)
        {
            using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(_width, _height, _width * 3, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, pBuffer))
            {
                bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX);
                if (SaveToDisc)
                {
                    String tempFile = _outFolder + _frameId + ".bmp";
                    if (File.Exists(tempFile))
                    {
                        fr1.lbl2(_frameId.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bitmap.Save(Path.Combine(_outFolder, _frameId + ".bmp"));
                    }
                    _frameId++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Images == null)
                        Images = new List<Bitmap>();
                    Images.Add((Bitmap)bitmap.Clone());
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Thel ine that is doing the updating is:

```
fr1.lbl2(_frameId.ToString();
```

Now i used breakpoint on this line in the new class and also in Form1 on the label2.Text in the public function and i saw that the label2 text is changing first its 0 then 1 then 2 and so on.

But in fact in realtime when im running the application the label2 dosent change its all the time the text saty as label2

This is the Form1 button click event when i click on it its doing the new class code:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            wmv = new Polkan.DataSource.WmvAdapter(@"d:\VIDEO0040.3gp", sf);
            wmv.SaveToDisc = true;
            wmv.Start();
            wmv.WaitUntilDone();
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean the UI is locked ? No in Form1 im updating other lables like in picturebox1 mouse move event i update in a lable1 the coordinates of the mouse movement and its working. I also tried in the run time code to change the label2 text to "hi" for testing and it worked. So something is worng here something else.

Comment: Doesn't `fr1` need to be the actual reference to the form you are using?  I see `fr1 = new AnimationEditor.Form1();`, which probably isn't the same instance of the form you are using.

Comment: LarsTech AnimationEditor is the namespace. And i used a breakpoint on the line label2.Text = text; in the lbl2 function in Form1 and saw that the text is changed. The variable text is changing 0,1,2....

Comment: Sure it works.  It looks like you have two forms though: one that you are using, and the one that your class created.  Different things.

Comment: LarsTech i also used a breakpoint now on the label2.Text = text in Form1 lbl2 function and saw that also text is changing and also the label2.Text is changing once its 0 then 1 then 2...and so on...mmmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the quick answer is to pass in the reference of the label to the class:

```
private Label lbl;

public WmvAdapter(string file, string outFolder, Label label) {
  // yada-yada-yada
  lbl = label;
}
```

Your routine would change to:

```
if (File.Exists(tempFile))
{
  lbl.Text = _frameId.ToString();
}
```

Your click event:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  wmv = new Polkan.DataSource.WmvAdapter(@"d:\VIDEO0040.3gp", sf, this.Label2);
  wmv.SaveToDisc = true;
  wmv.Start();
  wmv.WaitUntilDone();
}
```

The longer answer is to have your class raise an event and have your form listen for it.

Having your class be aware of the form is not the best coding practice.

Comment: Lars but in the new class i cant make private Form1 fr1; it dosent give me the option. Like Form1 dosent exist.

Comment: I edited and put my Form1 code the beginning of the Form1 code in my question post.

Comment: @user1434011 Update answer to just pass the label instead of the form.

Comment: Lars i tried your last edited code and in the new class on the line lbl.Text = _frameId.ToString(); im getting an exception: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'label2' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: Working ! I had to invoke the lbl in the new class like this: if (lbl.InvokeRequired)
                        {
                            lbl.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { lbl.Text = _frameId.ToString(); }));
                        }